# Exclude category by slug in pre_get_posts?

Tags: categories, pre-get-posts

Is it possible to exclude categories by slug in `pre_get_posts`? I can exclude categories by ID but it would be better if I can exclude posts by category name or slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with the following tax query:

```
'tax_query' => [
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => [ 'foo' ],
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ],
],
```

where the `foo` term slug is excluded.

Comment: That was my problem. Had missing characters. Thanks! `$query->set( 'tax_query', array(array('taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),'operator'=> 'NOT IN')));`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Sometimes it's better to fetch what you want, instead of what you don't want ;-)